# Web scraping multiple pages with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I collected all the necessary information from the first page, but don’t know how to collect information from all pages of the site. I try to find my solution in other stackoverflow topics but didn't understand anything. I will be very grateful if you help me with this.

my parsing site: https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page=1

source:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# my_url and cutoff mod_security 
my_url = Request('http://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page=1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
# grabs each name of player
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"top-area"})


for container in containers:
    playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
    print("BattlePass PlayerName: " + playerName)
```

source2

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# start page
i = 1
while True:
    link = 'https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page='+str(i)
    my_url = Request(
        link,
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    )
    i += 1  # increment page no for next run
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    if uClient.url != link:
        break
    page_html = uClient.read()
    # Check if there was a redirect
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # grabs each name of player
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-area"})

    # save all info to csv file
    filename = "BattlePassNicknames.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")

    headers1 = "Member of JAZE Battle Pass 2019\n"

    f.write(headers1)

    for container in containers:
        playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
        print("BattlePass PlayerName: " + playerName)

        f.write(playerName + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website redirects you to a different page if the `page` query parameter is greater than the last available page, you can use this to increment `page` till you are redirected. This is applicable if you already know the topic `id` (50 in this case).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# start page
i = 1
while True:
    link = 'https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page='+str(i)
    my_url = Request(
        link,
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    )
    i += 1  # increment page no for next run
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    if uClient.url != link:
        break
    page_html = uClient.read()
    # Check if there was a redirect
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # grabs each name of player
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-area"})

    for container in containers:
        playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
        print("BattlePass PlayerName: " + playerName)
```

Output

```
BattlePass PlayerName: VANTY3
BattlePass PlayerName: VANTY3
BattlePass PlayerName: KK#キング
BattlePass PlayerName: memories
BattlePass PlayerName: Waffel
BattlePass PlayerName: CynoBap
...
BattlePass PlayerName: Switchback
```

If you also want to try this out with random topic `id`s then you have to handle [urllib.error.HTTPError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError) somewhere in you code to deal with all the 404s etc..

Comment: Yea! it works, thank you! Is it work to another examples,sites(if i change the 'link' variable)?
And i think i want to add something, do you know which function is ideal so that these nicknames do not repeat. Or we need to make if statement to do that. If you know, where i can put it to my code?

Comment: uhh, when i try to save this file to 'csv' i get info only by last page of the site, all the previous pages info are lost. I updated my code in `Source2`

Comment: @Switchback you are writing to the file in 'w' mode. Try writing to it in 'a' mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but at csv he add ```headers1``` variable for each pages. Example: ```Member of JAZE Battle Pass 2019: kondik, dominator, switchback, Member of JAZE Battle Pass 2019: madness, vantuz, koshaka```

Comment: @Switchback Move only writing the headers out of the for loop.

Comment: nothing happened;( i think we need to change for loop but dunno how

Comment: ah, i'l fix it, nvm

Comment: @Switchback, You can always ask a new question if you are not able to.

Comment: do you know which function is ideal so that these nicknames do not repeat?

Comment: @Switchback simplest method would be to add to a set and then write to a file after the for loop https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

Comment: so it will check sets element, and if it `==` to another element then delete. dunno how to realize that. Can you help me if i drop final code to `source2`?

Comment: @Switchback Maybe better to ask a new ques.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for help anyway. I'l add new ques.